# Where question about which technology?

Tags: discussion

Where I can put question about how/which technology to choose for developing app?

Comment: 1) jump on your search engine of preference 2) research the possibilities 3) pick two or three that appeal to you 4) prototype them.

Answer (score 10):

Nowhere on SE. That question will always be so opinion-based its silly.